# AlmaLinux 9.0 で Squid 5.2 のメモリ使用量が増加し続けてしまう

Tags: linux, squid

AlmaLinux 9.0にメモリ8GB実装したシステム上で、Squid 5.2 を稼働させています。
現状、メモリ使用量がどんどん増加していき、最終的には一日でシステム停止まで行ってしまいます。

キャッシュ無効化、ファイルディスクリプタ拡張等を実施していますが、改善しません。

この事象について知見のある方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけますようよろしくお願いいたします。

```
acl yokk-net src 172.16.0.0/16
acl yokk-net src 172.20.0.0/16

acl SSL_ports port 80
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

http_access allow localhost

http_access allow yokk-net

http_access deny all

http_port 8080

cache_peer 10.255.205.100 parent 8080 0 proxy-only default
never_direct allow all

cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

cache_mem 254 MB

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

logformat timefm %{%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}tl %ts,%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %[un %Sh/%<a %mt

access_log /var/log/squid/access.log timefm

forwarded_for on

visible hostname insvsquid

shutdown_lifetime 10 seconds
```

Comment: メモリ使用量が増加状況はTOPで確認していますが、squid のプロセスのみが増加していきます。

Comment: squid や OS のログを確認すると、何かヒントになる情報があるかもしれません。

Comment: squid.conf の設定情報を教えてください。
また、SMP (worker>1) や rock 形式のディスクキャッシュを利用していませんでしょうか？
これらの場合、プロセス間のデータ共有に /dev/shm/ (メモリディスク)を使用します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。SMP (worker>1) や rock 形式のディスクキャッシュ　と言われるものがどういったものか知識がなくて申し訳ありません。squid.conf 上で設定するものでしょうか？　現在手元に最新config がないのでご提供は明日以降になってしまいます。最初にご説明するべきだったのですが、Hyper-V上で稼働するサーバで、上位にもう一つプロキシがある多段構成となっています。

Comment: クライアントからのアクセス数はかなり多いと思いますが、squid プロキシサーバとしての機能に問題はなく、特に遅延が発生しているという感じもありません。

Proxy専用サーバで、squid 以外のプロセスはごくわずかなものとなっています。

echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches  を実行しても　OSのキャッシュが削除されるだけで、squid で使われている　メモリに変化はありません。

squidプロセスのメモリ解放ができない状況のようで、８GBメモリを　１６GBに増設しても、枯渇する時間が遅くなるだけで数時間で結局システム停止になってしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

squid.conf の情報ありがとうございます。ほぼデフォルトで、SMP でも rock でもないですね。
キャッシュを無効(`cache deny all`)にしてもメモリ使用量が増え続けるのですか？
`cache_mem 254 MB` なので、全体のメモリ使用量はせいぜいその 3〜4 倍だと思うのですが、何ででしょうね。

古いドキュメントですが、下記 URL を参考に実機で解析していくしかないと思います。

https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidMemory
[(日本語訳)](https://www.robata.org/docs/squid/faq_8.html)

cachemgr.cgi の情報はコマンドラインから `squidclient -p 8080 mgr:mem` などでも参照できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。キャッシュ無効(cache deny all)にしても改善しません。squidclientでの確認もしましたが、対策の手がかりは見つけられませんでした。Version9のRedHat系OSの実環境での運用が始めてですので、OS側の設定に問題でもあるのでしょうか？負荷がかからない状況では、使用メモリの上昇はありません。　仮にアクセスが異常に増加したとしてこのようなメモリ使用量増加によるシステム停止などは起こりえるのでしょうか？現時点での対策としては。同じ構成の検証システムを構築し、JMeter等の負荷ツールを使って同様の事象が発生するかどうか確認し、再現できるようなら、とりあえずVersion8系で再構築し回避しようかとも考えています。

Comment: このバージョンのバグの可能性も考えていましたが、こんな情報がありました。https://www.spinics.net/lists/squid/msg94818.html　　やはり4.17での運用を考えたほうがいいんでしょうか？

Comment: @HJ60 スレッドを辿っていくとその問題は Fix されているようにも見えます。 https://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5132#c27 / 使用している Squid 5.2 は AlmaLinux の公式パッケージでしょうか？下手にバージョンを下げるより、新しいバージョンを試した方がよいかもしれません。5.x 系は 5.6 までリリースされているようです。 http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v5/

Comment: 手元の環境 squid-5.2-1.el9_0.1.x86_64 / AlmaLinux 9.0 では、キャッシュ無効(cache deny all)だとメモリ使用量はまったく増えないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの環境もAlmaLinux9.0で最新バージョン5.2-1 までアップデートしましたが事象発生しております。業務時間を過ぎると上昇度合は低くなりますので、時間外のアクセス数が下がる時間帯に一度サービス再起動をすると翌朝までシステム停止せずに持ちこたえます。5.2系以上はAlamaLinux9.0のパッケージとしては提供がなく、ソースもしくはrpmbuild して　4.17 か　５６　をインストールする形になるかと思います。ここで最新バージョンを選択してまた同じ事象が発生する可能性があるのであれば　4.17　で運用したほうがいいのかもというところです。

Comment: AlmaLinux9.0 に　8.0のsquid4.15 パッケージをインストールすることで、メモリ使用量の増加もなく、安定運用に乗せることができました。今後、対策バージョンのリリースが確認でき次第、アップデートを実施したいと思います。ありがとうございました。